# What is the shortcut command to install angular animation module and add its entry in module.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Scenario**

I'm learning Angular. When I wants to create a component or service I used below shortcut cmd command to create my component / service and import it in module.ts also add service entry in `providers`:

`ng g s components/login --m  app`

`ng g s services/data --m  app`

Now, what I want is when I've to install angular animation from cmd or any other dependency from cmd it will automatically add its import in module.ts file after installation. Let me know is there any shortcut command like above to install dependencies and add its import classes in module.ts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module installation has nothing to do with cli, as when you installing a new module you are using `npm` or `yarn` that just copied the thing in to `node_modules` folder.

However after you install the module you have to rely on your IDE capability e.g like [autoimport](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport) in case of vscode, the majority of IDE have that feature build in, so when you typing you get the imports automatically added to your `.ts` file.